# Unable to debug C Code in VSC, leads to "No such file or directory" error

Tags: c, json, file, debugging, directory

I wanted to debug my test code in VSC, but when try it I get this error message:
[Error message in VSC when launching the gdb JSON configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Gr9.png). The code compiles without issues and I can run it in the terminal outside and inside VSC.

task.json file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I thoroughly checked my directories and task.json and launch.json file. I could not spot any mistakes. The next thing I tried was running the folder on the desktop and it worked, but not in my main directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. More or less this:

> ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command
> "-exec-run". Error creating process /usr/bin/, (error 2).

To fix please try to use lower versions of `gcc`/`g++` (`v9` or so) and especially the lower version of `gdb` (`v10`, the experimental version installed was the problem, changed to `9.3` and Ok).

Comment: I will try this and update you.

Comment: I tried your approach and it did not work. Sadly.
I installed the MingW version 8.6 and tried to run it again. But now I get that errormessage:

"laung: program [Directory as before].vscode\launch.exe' does not exist

After re-editing the launch.json file to "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorld.exe"

But it ends in the same error message as before.

Comment: I think the compilation and execution of your program are not done in the correct directory, to check this, please check your current directory in the terminal section and see if the file you want to compile is in the same directory.

Comment: Solution:

The fix to the problem was enabling the beta for Unicode 8 in worldwide region on Windows 11 and 10.

You can find that option under "Clock and Regions"

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

To resolve the issue, follow the steps outlined below:

```
1. Access the Windows Control Panel. You can do this by opening File Explorer and typing 'Control Panel' (without quotes) in the address bar, then pressing Enter.
2. Once in the Control Panel, navigate to the 'Clock and Region' section.
3. Select the 'Region' option, which will open a new screen.
4. In the newly opened screen, locate and click on 'Administrative'.
5. Look for the button labeled "Change system location" within the Administrative settings.
6. Enable the option that says "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for world language support".

7. Restart your computer to apply the changes.
```

This worked for me on Windows 11 64-bit